# Select EndDate >= GETDATE() is not working?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have database table called Deals which contains StartDate and EndDate. If EndDate is 2013-05-31 then `EndDate >= GETDATE()` is selecting all dates before 2013-05-31 but not including 2013-05-31 it-self. In the database I have 2013-05-31 00:00:00.000

Comment: What datatype does the EndDate have, is it a DATETIME?

Comment: @TomasPastircak yes, actually it's  2013-05-31 00:00:00.000. I think 0 are causing this issue

Comment: It would be helpful to see your SQL statement.

Comment: @RickS, the SQL is simple select with above condition

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`GETDATE()` returns a datetime, so the current time is causing a problem. 
Use:

```
EndDate >= CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
CONVERT(varchar(11),Endate,101)>=CONVERT(varchar(11),GETDATE(),101)
```

**Edit**

Why accepted answer is better ?

Applying conversion functions on table column result in loss of indexing on that column if indexing has been applied on that column